# Have one query regarding sum if formula

Tags: excel

I am working in excel using `SUMIF` formula, my data is as follows:

```
Region  Opr    Qty    Cost     Combo(col B&A)
192     114    50     500      104192
192     104    453    548      104192
192     114    125    54654    114192
192     114    155    1545     114192
192     124    12     1553     124192
192     134    12222  1554545  134192
192     174    256    15478    174192
192     104    12     1555     104192
192     104    210    1156     104192
192     114    47     448953   114192
192     114    29     59479    114192
192     124    124    32451    124192
192     134    114    290240   134192
4192     10    210    115656   104192
4192     10    47     44896    104192
4192     11    29     12866    114192
4192     11    549    290240   114192
4192     12    124    59480    124192
4192     13    114    61343    134192
4192     17    310    45339    174192
4192     10    56     32451    104192
4192     10    103    82483    104192
4192     11    685    111380   114192
4192     11    646    201858   114192
4192     12    26     6489     124192
4192     13    87     44543    134192
```

If you see the last column it's giving same combination result but the operator and region are not always the same. I want to do `SUMIF` against Region which is throwing wrong values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B27&A2:A27)*1<>E2:E27)*1)
```

If the concatenation of column B to A is not equal to the Combo, count as 1, then add all the 1 together in `SUMPRODUCT`.

Change the range accordingly.

The `*1` convert any text to number.

Comment: thanks, i want the answer in following format   192  
  
 Qty Cost
114 406 565131
104 675 3259
124 136 34004
134 12336 1844785
174 256 15478
10 0 0
11 0 0
12 0 0
13 0 0
17 0 0
 and 4192  
  
 Qty Cost
114 0 0
104 0 0
124 0 0
134 0 0
174 0 0
10 416 278456
11 1909 616344
12 150 65969
13 201 105886
17 310 45339.2631
 where i will select region 192 and 4191 and the values and qty will change

Comment: @user3437610 Sorry, I can't read that format. Could you specify the format in your question by editing it please?

Comment: There will be filter for selecting region, once region is slected qty and cost will be dispalyed against each operator. So here region is 192 or 4192 and operators are column B. qty and cost is calculated using sumif formula now. but due to region number is such that for region 192 and operator 114 gives me combo of 114192, which is exactly same as region 4192 and operator 11 (11&4192 which is 114192). So duplication is occuring.

Comment: @user3437610 Can you control Combo? I would then suggest you do `B&"-"&A` (i.e. add a dash in between the opr and  region).

Comment: thanks a lot. its working. but then i have 100 such regions and approx 250 operators, so huge change. thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3437610 Does that mean that everything works now?